# How to display special html characters in title tag

Tags: php, html, url

I have a anchor tag that links to a php page, I would like to use special characters in the url parameter `title`

The string I would like to pass in the url:

`Which is better approach to use href="#" or href="javascript:void(0)"`

My anchor tag href will look like this:

`mypage.php?title=Which is better approach to use href="#" or href="javascript:void(0)"`

on my php page, when i echo $_GET["title"]; I only get part of the string:

`Which is better approach to use href="`

how to display exact title which i used in my anchor tag

Comment: Can you try give more detail in for question and explain as much as you can, I'm not sure what it is you're trying to ask...

Comment: I agree with @ForceBru . You should care a lot more about the question ok.

Comment: If I'm reading that properly you forgot to put a `"` at the end of your `href` attribute, which means your html is corrupted and bad.

Comment: i want to display the exact value of title when i echo title value

Comment: How to display `special html characters` in title tag. Well the title tag is `<title>This</title>` that goes in the head of the page but you don't have anything to show your attempts of putting any text into the `title` You should edit your question as the question title is very misleading and you don't show any sign of `special html characters` either.

Comment: Again, **too bad formatting**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enconde the string before sending it to the title variable.

**Example**:

```
$title = 'Which is better approach to use href="#" or href="javascript:void(0)"'
echo '<a href="mypage.php?title='. urlencode($title) . '">';

// and to get the title
echo urldecode($_GET["title"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to output your links and [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to echo them in the other page:

First page:

```
<?php
$link = urlencode('Which is better approach to use href="#" or href="javascript:void(0)"');

echo '<a href="mypage.php?title=' . $link . '">a link</a>';
?>
```

And on mypage.php you'll do:

```
<?php
echo urldecode( $_GET['title'] );
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

The PHP $_GET['title'] is the variable "title" of the get array which are in fact the variables after the ? in an url.

```
<a href="index.php?title=TheTitle">test</a>
```

this would show TheTitle

But you'll probably want to url escape the title.

```
<a href="mypage.php?title=<?php echo urlencode('Which is better approach to use href="#"') ?>">Link</a>
```

Comment: Do not know - then do not answer :)

Comment: I pointed in the right direction. I know it is possible.
by the way it is urlencode($string)